# Missing OS on e OS mac USB install

Tags: release-loki, system-installation, boot, grub, usb-drive

Re:

- elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20170814.iso
- mac etcher-1.1.2.dmg

Hi

Shasum zero[d] referenced image file, but elementary OS installer could not install grub correctly on the target USB drive, reporting:

```
Missing OS
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

It appears grub got installed on mac internal Hard Disk, even though elementary OS installer pointed it to USB drive.
Thanks!

einer

[*reference*](https://github.com/aroman/elementary-on-a-mac/tree/2017-updates)

Answer (score 0):

Been there done that.
First, did you have a current time machine? the MAC EFI (their improvement on BIOS) will see that and restore you to MACOS. Boot with super key (GOOGLE THAT) with the time machine drive plugged in and recover from there.

Secondly, the MACOS and your data is probably still there, minus the boot instructions.  You will find that a local PC shop for a few $$ may be able to run 0101001010 recovery on the disk.  Elementary OS went to the USB drive and the boot loader went to the Local Disk.

Thirdly, In order to dual boot or just boot elementary, the MAC EFI would need to be replaced with third party rEFInd http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/or others' newer tool so that on boot up both MACOS and elementaryos disks can be found and will be boot choice.

Comment: Moses wrote: 'Thirdly, In order to dual boot or just boot elementary, the MAC EFI would need to be replaced with third party rEFInd http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/or others' newer tool so that on boot up both MACOS and elementaryos disks can be found and will be boot choice.'

Comment: Installed rEFInd, which displays e OS grub HD icon, mac HD icon and e OS USB icon.  Hitting grub HD icon brings up grub shell, but NO e OS boot! mac HD icon boots OS X and e OS USB icon displays: 'MISSING OS . . 'HTH_einer